# Connecting to MQTT Broker with paho and TLS fails

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to connect to my companies MQTT Broker but it does not seem to work. Every time I execute my code

```py
client = mqtt.Client()

client.username_pw_set(username="admin", password="admin")
client.tls_set(ca_certs="ca.crt", certfile=None, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)

client.connect("18.221.19.47", 8883, 60)
```

I get the same error

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:981)

As you can see, I have tried setting the TLS version explicitly to TLSv1.2 but it still says that `sslv3`is being used. What can I do to use TLSv1.2?

Comment: Your client can't force a broker to use TLS1.2 if the broker isn't configured to use TLS1.2. It's like trying to force someone to speak Japanese who only speaks English. Your choices are use protocols that the broker supports or pressure the people who maintain the broker to upgrade to more recent, more secure protocols.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` ?